# Add twitter widget into extjs panel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, extjs, twitter

I am new to ExtJs. 
I have created a twitter widget on twitter. It just works fine on simple html page.
As twitter says you just need to include

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23certain" data-widget-id="widget-id">Tweets about "#certain"</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Putting this to an html creates a beautiful widget on UI but i want this to include into an extjs panel. It only creates a hyperlink and not widget. Can anyone help me.

Comment: i tried to include it in html, 'iframe' tag etc

Comment: It doesn't work for me when I paste your code into a plain HTML page.

Comment: You will need to update data-widget-id. A simple widget can be created from  twitter > settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone is looking for an answer, here is how I have achieved it,

```
var tweetHtml = '<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/search" data-widget-id="your-widget-id" height="' + height + '" >Tweets for Certain Mobile</a>';
var dialog = new Ext.Panel({
    xtype: 'panel',
    height: '100%',
    border: false,
    scroll: 'vertical',
    listeners: {
        single: true, // Remove the listener after first invocation
        afterrender: function() {
            ! function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                    p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
                if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.id = id;
                    js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }
            }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
        }
    },
    html: tweetHtml
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the config object that you pass to the constructor of the Ext.Panel, just include a line for the `html` property. The value of the property is just the HTML string that defines your Twitter widget.

Answer (score 1):

Move the javascript part into an `afterrender` listener of your panel:

```
Ext.widget('panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,title: "Tweeter!"
    ,width: 500
    ,height: 300
    ,html: '<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23certain" data-widget-id="widget-id">Tweets about "#certain"</a>'
    ,listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
            !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using sencha and it is throwing Object #<Object> has no method 'widget'

Comment: updating sencha version is tedious

Comment: Sencha? Sencha is a company... I suppose you mean ext3.4? Or Sencha touch? Anyway, the only relevant part in my example is the `html` property and the listener... That should be straightforward to port that to any Sencha product...